# GDB on NetBeans 8.2 not starting (Windows)

Tags: c++, c, windows, netbeans, gdb

I've successfully installed NetBeans 8.2 on my system. I've also installed MinGW and MSYS to make it compile C/C++ projects and it works flawlessly. The problem is that whenever I try to debug a program it gives me two errors:

> Selected console type is not supported in your configuration, using
>   External terminal instead

and

> GDB has unexpectedly stopped with return -1.073.741.701

and GDB is stuck loading until i press `Cancel`.

I noticed that if I go to `C:\MinGW\bin\gdb.exe` it says that the application cannot be started (Error code: `0xc00007b`).

---

Maybe that's because I followed the [official tutorial](https://netbeans.org/community/releases/72/cpp-setup-instructions.html#compilers) for installing MinGW and MSYS, but I wasn't able to install GDB correctly because point 15 says:

> Unzip the gdb-7.0-2-mingw32-bin.tar.gz to your C:\MinGW directory so
>   that the gdb executable is installed into your C:\MinGW\bin directory.

but if I unzip the files, there are `bin` and share `directories` (which overlap with the existing ones), so I chose to cancel.

---

I could have found the issue, but I'm not sure. I ran [Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) on `gdb.exe` and it reds out `ZLIB1.DLL` and `KERNEL32.DLL`. Do I need the 32-bit version of them? If so, where can I find the downloads?

Screenshot:

[image: Screenshot of Dependency Walker]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved: as I mentioned in my edit, the problem was the 64-bit version of ZLIB1.dll, so I downloaded the [32-bit version](https://www.opendll.com/index.php?file-download=zlib1.dll&arch=32bit&version=1.2.3.0&dsc=zlib-data-compression-library#) and put it inside `C:\MinGW\bin`. Now everything works perfectly. Thanks to @bremen_matt for suggesting me that it was a dependency issue.

Answer (score 1):

Not unzipping the files is almost definitely the problem. There is probably a dependency that doesn't, causing a runtime error.

Comment: I tried running Dependency Walker on gdb,exe and it gives me a bunch of `API-MS-WIN-CORE-*.DLL` missing. What should I do?

Comment: Another thing I noticed is that it reds out `ZLIB1.DLL`. I'll update my question with a screenshot.

Comment: Did you download the 64 bit or 32 bit of mingw?  If the 64 bit, then it wouldn't hurt to download the 32 bit and try that.

Comment: I should add that you may want to consider switching to cygwin since gdb and everything should be in there.